# AWK print all regex matches on every line

Tags: awk

I have the following text input:

```
lorem <a> ipsum <b> dolor <c> sit amet,
consectetur <d> adipiscing elit <e>, sed 
do eiusmod <f> tempor
incididunt ut
```

As seen in the text, the appearances of **<**?**>** is not fixed and can appear 0 or multiple times on the same line.

**Only using awk** I need to output this:

```
<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```

I tried this awk script:

```
awk '{
  match($0,/<[^>]+>/,a);           // fill array a with matches
  for (i in a) {
    if (match(i, /^[0-9]+$/) != 0) // ignore non numeric indices
      print a[i]
  }
}' somefile.txt
```

but this only outputs the first match on every line:

```
<a>
<d>
<f>
```

Is there some way of doing this with `match()` or **any other built-in function**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple `gnu-awk` alternative solution using `patsplit`:

```bash
awk '
n = patsplit($0, m, /<[^>]+>/) {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      printf "%s", m[i] (i < n ? OFS : ORS)
}' file

<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Using FPAT is a good alternative if the only thing I'm interested in is the content of <?>. But if my records had fields separated by spaces and inside that fields I have the brackets placeholder (eg.: "word1 w<1>d2 word") things cat get complicated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

With GNU `awk` you could use its OOTB variable named `FPAT` and could try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v FPAT='<[^>]*>' '
NF{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"") $i
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 11):

`match()` doesn't work the way you think it does; to find a variable number of matches you would need to first `match()` the first pattern, strip off that pattern, then `match()` the remainder of the input for the next pattern, and repeat until no more matches in the current line; eg:

```
awk '
{ out=sep=""                                     # init variables for new line
  while (match($0,/<[^>]+>/)) {                  # find 1st match
        out=out sep substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    # build up output line
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)             # strip off 1st match and prep for next while() check
        sep=OFS                                  # set field separator for follow-on matches
  }
  if (out) print out
}' somefile.txt
```

Another idea uses the `split()` function, eg:

```
awk '
{ n=split($0,a,/[<>]/)                           # split line on dual delimiters "<" and ">"
  out=sep=""
  for (i=2;i<=n;i=i+2) {                         # step through even numbered array entries; assumes line does not contain any standalone "<" or ">" characters !!!
      out=out sep "<" a[i] ">"                   # build output line
      sep=OFS 
  }
  if (out) print out
}
' somefile.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming there are no stray angle brackets, use either `<` or `>` as a **field separator** and print every **second** field:

```bash
awk -F'[<>]' '{for (i=2; i <= NF; i += 2) {printf "<%s> ", $i}; print ""}' data
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple `awk` solution based on regexps:

```bash
awk '{ gsub(/^[^<]*|[^>]*$/,""); gsub(/>[^<]*</,"> <") } NF'
```

<sup>**edit:** using `NF` instead of `$0 != ""`; thanks @EdMorton</sup>

For each line:

- strip all chars from the left up to the first `<` (excluded) or up to the end-of-line when `<` isn't found.
- strip all chars from the right up to the first `>` (excluded) or up to the start-of-line when `>` isn't found.
- replace what's between each `>` and `<` pair with a space character.
- print the result when it isn't empty

###### example

```
lorem <a a> ipsum <b> dolor <c> sit amet,
consectetur <d> adipiscing elit <e>, sed 
do eiusmod <f> tempor
<g>incididunt ut<h><i>
h>ell<o
<j>
```

###### output

```
<a a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
<g> <h> <i>
<j>
```

---

**Remark:** With exactly the same logic you can use `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/^[^<]*//; s/[^>]*$//; s/>[^<]*</> </g; /^$/d'
```

Answer (score 8):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
lorem <a> ipsum <b> dolor <c> sit amet,
consectetur <d> adipiscing elit <e>, sed 
do eiusmod <f> tempor
incididunt ut
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="<[^>]*>"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is `<` followed by zero-or-more (`*`) non(`^`)-`>` followed by `>`. For each line I do `$1=$1` to provoke rebuilt, so now line are found fields joined by space, which I then `print`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: maybe streamline `awk 'BEGIN { … } {$1=$1;print}'` to simply ::::::::::::: :::::::::::; :::::::::::::::: `awk NF=NF FPAT='<[^>]*>'` while retaining all functionality of original ?

Answer (score 5):

***INPUT***

```
lorem <a> ipsum <b> dolor <c> sit amet,
consectetur <d> adipiscing elit <e>, sed 
do eiusmod <f> tempor
incididunt ut
```

***CODE***

> ```
> mawk -F'^[^<]+|[^>]+$' 'gsub(">[^<]*<","> <",$!(NF=NF))^_*/./' OFS=
> ```

***OUTPUT***

```
<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `gnu awk` with gensub. You can capture the angle brackets with optional surrounding spaces and match the rest.

In the replacement use group 1 surrounded with a single space.

```
awk '{$0 = gensub(/ *(<[^>]*>) *|[^<>]+/, " \\1 ", "g"); $1=$1}1' file
```

Output

```
<a> <b> <c>
<d> <e>
<f>
```